# Is it possible to change edittext's location in layout when clicking on it?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have two listviews in an activity and an edittext between them. Is it possible to change edittext's position when clicking on it. i.e. hide first listview so that only second listview with edittext on top will remain?

I want upper listview to be gone when I'm typing (i.e. edittext is focused, keyboard is visible). When I stop typing (edittext is not focused, keyboard is gone) listview should be visible

Comment: Set visibility gone.

Comment: Mean, you want to hide first listview, on tapping on `EditText`.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, I feel. Could you please provide a diagram to illustrate what you wish to achieve?

Comment: I agree with @W.K.S What do you want exactly? Post more details.

Comment: @Yusuf Abdullaev: Its too complex but if u want to go for it anyways then it can b done programatically adding view and setting it.

Comment: you can do that programmatically, you can set visibility gone for your first listview. and for edittext, you need to provide params to move it.

Comment: @W.K.S Ok, sorry. I want upper listview to be gone when I'm typing (i.e. edittext is focused, keyboard is visible). When I stop typing (edittext is not focused, keyboard is gone) listview should be visible –

Answer (score 0):

yes...
you can do that

1. set visibility gone of listview1 by click on edittext. so it will automatically goes upperside

Answer (score 0):

Like Piyush Gupta commented, you want to set a reference to the view that you want to make disappear, then tell it to disappear.

```
//Declare a private variable to reference the listview at the class level
private ListView listView1

@override
public void onCreate(bundle savedInstanceState)
this.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
listView1 = findViewById(R.Id.listview1);
listView1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then in the `OnClick` method (cant recall what its called right now, dont have `Android Studio` installed) call

```
listView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to achieve desired effect with view.setTranslationX(float value) & view.setTranslationY(floatvalue) methods in onclick() of the view.